# how to refresh the gridview after it filters (Dynamic) using LinqDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, linqdatasource

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1"> 
    <Columns> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name" ReadOnly="True"  
            SortExpression="UserName" /> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Full Name" ReadOnly="True"  
            SortExpression="FullName" /> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" ReadOnly="True"  
            SortExpression="Email" /> 
       <asp:BoundField DataField="LastLoginDate" HeaderText="Last Login" ReadOnly="True"  
            SortExpression="LastLoginDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMMM yyyy}"/> 
       <asp:HyperLinkField Text="Edit" DataNavigateUrlFields="UserId" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Pages/UsersMaintenance/CreateEditUser.aspx?UserId={0}" /> 
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView> 

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="MyDataContextDataContext" onselecting="LinqDataSource_Selecting">  
        <WhereParameters>  
           <asp:Parameter Name="Subject" /> 
        </WhereParameters>  
</asp:LinqDataSource> 

 public void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
        {
                this.LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters["Subject"].DefaultValue =  this.txtSubject.Text;
               e.Result = reporterRepo.GetInquiries();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my gridview was in updatepanel thats why it was not refreshing the gridview

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, or modify it till it works. If I'm correct I did something like this before:

```
public void LinqDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
   this.LinqDataSource1.WhereParameters["Subject"].DefaultValue =  this.txtSubject.Text;
   GridView2.DataBind();
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: does not refresh and i am reterving the correct data from the database and does not bind the gridview and still throws me all the rows instead of 2 rows (based on my search result)

Comment: Make sure your intial databind on pageload is not executed on postbacks. Be aware that the Selecting Eventhandler is called after the Page_Load event.

Comment: i dont have anything that bind to gridview in the page_load